# How can I find an emergency vet?

Tags: first-aid, veterinarian

Something happened to my pet and I know I need to get to the veterinarian as quickly as I can, but my regular veterinarian is closed! What should I do?

Comment: I'm not currently having this problem, but thought the information would be good to have available.

Comment: Related [I can't afford vet treatment, what are my options?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/18810/13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call your regular one. Most (if not all) should have an alternative/emergency number on their answering machine, which you should be able to call. If that doesn't work call the directory assistance.

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, while some vet surgeries offer emergency consultations and it is always worth calling up to see if they deal with emergencies, there is a service called [Vets Now](http://www.vets-now.com/find-an-emergency-vet/). They have 53 emergency clinics open across the country, mostly in the Midlands and South of England, open when regular vets are closed.

Alternatively, from the [RSPCA website](http://www.rspca.org.uk/adviceandwelfare/pets/findavet),

> Vetfone is a 24-hour service, which works like an NHS Direct for pets, and anyone can call. It is staffed exclusively by UK-qualified veterinary nurses with years of experience.
>
> You can pay upfront or have the call charged to your bill, and the cost is typically less than an initial consultation.
>
> Visit www.vetfone.co.uk for more information.

They will help you decide what the best course of action is, especially if you live too far from a Vets Now clinic, or are unsure if your pet needs an emergency vet.

Comment: I second the suggestion to call your local spca -- or ask your vet for advice befote an emergency arises.  In my area the spca runs one of the best veterinary hospitals I've heard of, with 24 hour emergency coverage.