# Our kitten has had constant urinary issues after an initial urinary infection, vet bills are exorbitant. Advice?

Tags: cats, health, urination, urinary-tract-disease

We got a kitten that was dribbling pee everywhere, crying and struggling when he peed, and constantly licking his groin. We noticed he rarely urinated, and that he would not drink water from bowls, a pinch test showed that he was pretty dehydrated, and he has been eating dry food. We switched to wet food, and started adding water, and his dehydration went away and he regularly voided.

He turned out to have a very bad UI, he had a swollen penis and was peeing blood. We got him on two weeks of antibiotics and the swelling went away, and he stopped straining to pee, stopped licking himself...etc But the dribbling never stopped.

Our vet wanted to do an exam, ui, and antibiotics weekly. At the sound of $185/w ($55/exam, $65/UA, $65/antibiotics), after we've already spent over $400 on vet bills for this kitten. Something we cannot afford by any stretch. We've been feeding him urinary food, and his symptoms have not changed in the last two weeks. He still dribbles, but doesn't strain to pee or lick his groin after. He still does not drink water from bowls, so we mix a decent amount of water in with his wet food 3x a day.

We decided to take him to another clinic, and they did a UA and ultrasound for $130. The UA came back positive, and they want to do a culture sensitivity test for $250 to determine the appropriate type of antibiotic to use.

At this point, we're already pulling out of savings for our next rent check as a result of these vet bills. We keep going around in circles with this diagnostics stuff, but with no resolution, and no end in sight.

Is there anything we can do? We really don't know what to do next, no one will want a sick kitten, and we love his personality, but he's holed up in the bathroom 24/7 because he dribbles pee everywhere. I'm not sure if a shelter will take him, and the original owner wants nothing to do with it.

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/i-cant-afford-vet-treatment-what-are-my-options

Comment: Are there any cat-rescues around your area?

Comment: Did they see any stones?