# My dog drinks water like he never got any and drinks his urine

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, toilet-training

I have a 16 week old puppy. I don't understand why he drinks water like he never had any. Then, he urinates half a minute after consumption. If he is out of the crate, he will try to get back in to pee inside. Lastly, he drinks his urine.

I've done everything. He won't even always urinate on a puppy mat. I'm just ready to give up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dog Drinking and Peeing Habits - Cushings?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19099/dog-drinking-and-peeing-habits-cushings)

Comment: It sounds like he is in a cage/crate during the day.  Does he have water in the cage/crate with him?

Comment: you need to provide more information about your dog,lots more details please the more information you give the better answer you can expect.

Comment: More info required: How much time does he spend in his crate every day?  Have you taken him to the vet?  How much water does he drink?  How often does he pee?  How often do you let him out of the cage to pee?  Does he have water in his cage with him?  What sort of food are you feeding him?  Did you thoroughly clean his cage and bedding after he peed in it? Also, frankly, if he is 16 weeks you probably only had him for 8 weeks.  If you're already ready to give up you may have to ask yourself if you are the right person for a pet - he will be with you for around 15 years.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a broad topic. You should give more information.

From what you say, it could be something physical so take it to the vet just in case.

But I think this is more of a behavioral concern. If the dog is in a crate, it's probably because he is disobedient in a certain aspect.

If the dog lacks discipline you'll get this kind of problems, like destroying furniture and some other weird behaviors.

You should train, a lot. At that age, he should be doing his things outside, not struggling to use a mat.

A significant amount of time, measured in lots of hours, needs to be invested in walking your dog on the streets outside and socializing it with other dogs. When a dog does not behave instinctively (and drinking urine isn't aligned with their instincts, because they love smell marks) it's because something is not quite right on his daily basis.

Judge yourself and, if you can't or you don't know how to do it, contact a professional. You are probably the only one guilty of that behavior.