# My Rottweiler puppy is sick

Tags: dogs, health

I have a Rottweiler pup who is about 12-13 weeks old. About Tuesday he became uncharacteristicly lethargic and wouldn’t eat. We took him to the vet and he received some fluids and an injection to help with digestion and we were told to monitor him. It is now Thursday and I’m becoming increasingly worried about him. He still refused any food we tried to give him, even treats. He will drink water now, which is an improvement, but he has white colored diarrhea and yellow throw up. We currently do not have the money to afford for the vet to run extensive tests but he’s getting thinner by the day. 
Does anyone have an idea of what illness this could be or what could’ve caused this? How can I help him? How can I coax him back into eating without irritating his stomach again?

Comment: Related [I can't afford vet treatment, what are my options?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/i-cant-afford-vet-treatment-what-are-my-options)

Comment: Did he have the same symptoms when you first visited the vet? If the vet doesn't know about the diarhea and vomitting, call them immediately and ask them how to proceed. They probably know what's going on and won't need to do more test.

Comment: @Elmy. Hey, yes the vet does know about his symptoms and we’ve kept them updated since our last visit. They know about the diarrhea and vomiting but they still said that it could be caused by a variety of things so they wanted to do tests to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get some nutrients into him. There are special powders to feed malnourished dogs, but there are natural alternatives, too.

In order of best choice, try to get:

- one whole unseasoned chicken (fresh or frozen doesn't matter) or
- 3 - 4 marrow bones of pigs or cattle, preferably with some meat (usually cut into thick slices) or
- unseasoned chicken wings or
- 2 pigs feet

If you got a chicken or chicken wings, break the bones in the legs and wings by smacking them with the blunt edge of a sturdy knife or cleaver. Put it into a pot and just barely cover it in water. If there are intestines with the chicken, put them in as well. Add no more than <sup>1</sup>/<sub>4</sub> of a teaspoon of salt and let it simmer on low heat for several hours. Some people cook it for 12 hours, but 4 should be enough.

When it's finished and cooled, first give him a bowl of the broth. For the next meal, add a little amount of meat or marrow to the broth and blend it very fine. For the next meal, add a little bit more of the meat. If there is no meat because you got clean bones, cook some unseasoned rice and blend it with the broth.

Breaking the bones lets the nutritious marrow dissolve into the broth. The salt helps normalize the mineral content of your puppies blood, but it must not be too much because he isn't drinking enough. The smell should help his appetite. Broth is very easy on the stomach but contains lots of nutrients that your puppy needs right now.

When he starts eating again, add <sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub> of his normal food to the broth, the next day <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub>, next day give him a normal amount and soak it in the broth. It's important to switch slowly back to normal food to not upset his stomach again.

**Never feed cooked bones to any animal! They become brittle and can shatter while being eaten, causing severe injuries or choking.**

If your puppy doesn't eat the broth-meat-soup you need to see the vet again. Small bodies are vulnerable to imbalance of minerals in the blood and your puppy is already weakened.