# Am I losing my cat?

Tags: cats, medicines, diseases, death, stress

So my cat is very lovable.

We recently had a bad flea infestation in the house because of construction. I mean we had everything bad. So about a week ago I noticed that he had fleas, we had given him the treatments and combed him. He was still hiding a lot but usually came out to eat.

As of recent days he stopped eating his dry food, and isn't using the bathroom. He sits in his own filth, has lost a ton of weight, and doesn't move from that spot at all.

I checked him again, he has the fleas still. So I panicked and thought what if he had them all this time? So I give him a treatment, waited a day or two and nothing, he's still not eating unless it's wet food and still doesn't use the bathroom or move.

I just gave him a bath today with flea treatment shampoo.

I can't afford a vet, but I need help, please.

Comment: if a cat stops eating it is an emegency,and it needs help from a vet as soon as possible.you might take a look here [I can't afford vet treatment, what are my options?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/i-cant-afford-vet-treatment-what-are-my-options) to see what options you have to get your cat treated.

Comment: This drastic change in behavior doesn't sound like it's caused by fleas. It could be anything from stress to illness to parasites. I'm afraid we won't be able to diagnose your cat and you need to go to a vet.

Comment: You need to afford a vet if you want your cat to live.

Answer (score 4):

This may be severe illness, having the veterinary see your cat is urgent.

Vet examination does not have to bind you into further payments due to an expensive treatment, if such is needed. You may even find out that there is a simple remedy to your cat's condition costing little or nothing.