# My cat threw up after eating a fake succulent plant

Tags: cats, health

About noon yesterday, my 5 month old cat threw up what seemed to be pieces of a fake succulent plant I had in my kitchen.

I had thrown the plant away 2 weeks before this. He threw up about three time in that day. He seemed fine and all, but now he won't eat at all. I've seen him act like he's hungry but when I give him the food, he just smells it and walks off.

My other cat is perfectly fine and eats his food. I want to take him to a vet, but I'm afraid me and my mom are very short on money at the moment.

Please help me, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if a cat stop eating it is an emergency and it needs to be examined by a vet as soon as possible,there is some options to get it treated https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18810/i-cant-afford-vet-treatment-what-are-my-options if you live in some of these areas.

Answer (score 3):

Your cat has eaten plastic and this is really dangerous so, for this reason alone, you need to take the cat to the vet.

Your cat isn't eating and this is an emergency so you need to take your cat to the vet as soon as you can. Failing to bring the cat to the vet puts your cat's life in danger.

This is the reason why you need to get your cat treated: If a cat does not eat for more than 24 hours, the body of the cat starts to move the body fat to the liver where it will be converted to energy. The problem is a cat's liver is not able to do this at the speed needed. This means more and more fat will build up in the liver tissue and damage the liver cells. This will be deadly if not treated in time.

Link to more information: https://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/digestive/c_ct_hepatic_lipidosis

It does look like skinny cats can go longer than fat cats can before fatty liver syndrome develops so if your cat is fat you will have less time to get it treated before it gets deadly.

Answer (score -1):

While vomiting isn't always a sign that something is wrong in cats, it sounds like he has eaten something which disagreed with him (the succulent plant) and now he is put off food.

Before you take him to the vet, try him on some very plain food, such as plain chicken, or tuna from a can. See if you can feed him with your hand. It might be something to do with the bowl he eats from.

If he still won't eat, you need to get him to the vet.

Comment: Is it safe to defer taking the cat to the vet? This was a fake plant which means it may have plastics or anything else in it.

Comment: @Henders to be honest, you are chancing it, but he might be fine. My cat has previously swallowed very small pieces of plastic which have not caused him harm, and eventually nature took its course and he passed it. You should monitor his stool for a while. If he passes it, and still doesn't seem to want to eat, you need to get him to the vet.